# How to get req.body,operationName in Apollo Graphql with Next js App Route

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem where I need the value of req.body.operationName on the apollo server that I run with next js 13 App Route http://localhost:3000/api/v1/graphql

the problem arises because if you use express js with apollo graphql it will be easy to get the value of req.body.operationName. but because I use next js 13 app route the req.body.operationName is not there.

req.body.operationName I need for context on Apollo server. here is my code in api/v1/graphql/route.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from "@as-integrations/next";
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { typeDefs } from "@/graphql/schema";
import { resolvers } from "@/graphql/resolvers";
import context from "@/graphql/context";

export type Context = {
  req: NextApiRequest;
  res: NextApiResponse;
};

const server = new ApolloServer<Context>({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});

const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server, {
  context: async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.operationName === "signIn")
    return { req, res }
  },
});

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}
```

can someone explain to me how to get the req.body.operationName value in next js. I need that value to know which graphql query is being requested

I want to see the value of req.body.operationName so I can determine how to manage the request.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the request payload by using the query property for GET requests and the body property for POST requests. Try something like this,

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
  context: ({ req, res }) => {
    const operationName = req.method === "GET" ? req.query.operationName : req.body.operationName
    console.log(operationName) // logging it here..
    return { req, res }
  },
})

const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server)
```